# Import Emacs Keyboard Configuration Into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse, in the menu, I can go to Window -> Preferences -> Keys and set the Scheme to "Emacs." I can also click "Export" at the bottom-right hand side of the dialog to export a .CSV file containing a listing of my keyboard mappings.

How do I re-import this configuration into a different installation of Eclipse? The File -> Import option seems to neither support .CSV files or a specific keyboard configuration file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try exporting and importing all of your preferences

**Export**
File->Export...->General->Preferences

**Import**
File->Import...->General->Preferences

Comment: Note that you can select to export only "Keys preferences" when doning the Export File->Export...->General->Preferences so that should do it.

Comment: Oh nice.  I didn't know that feature was in there.  I've always just exported my entire preferences.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Something that should work is to export all preferences and then import them in the other install. But I know no way to do that for the keyboard prefs alone.

I agree that it would make sense. I suggest you open a bug report against Eclipse. Maybe it really is a missing feature (or the solution is too simple and we don't see it).

Comment: Apparently, Eclipse gives you options as to *which* preferences to export. The options I currently see are CVS repos, key preferences, and JREs. 

I now see that the previous question answers this. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

The key configuration is relative to each workspace. You can find your configuration files at your workspace directory:

```
workspace
  /.metadata
    /.plugins
```

I haven't figured out yet which of these files corresponds to your keyboard configuration. There's also a user configuration folder at your home folder (~/.eclipse in GNU/Linux systems). You'll probably find the right file somewhere over these directories.