# Is there any way to import Eclipse 3.4 keybindings/keyboard preferences into Eclipse 3.6?

Tags: eclipse

I've tried exporting from the Eclipse 3.4 Keys pref pane, but this creates a .csv file and Eclipse 3.6 only seems to want to import .epf files (via File -> Import...). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, Eclipse 3.6 (and probably older versions) cannot import key bindings from CSV files.  If you have only a .csv file of the key bindings and you're not able to re-export those bindings as a .epf, you are completely out of luck.

As most people would expect, changing the file extension from .csv to .epf will not work.  EPF files contain XML, while CSV files are, well, comma-separated values.  One could probably write a program to convert the CSV to EPF, but I've not seen one already available.

Answer (score 4):

There is a similar question at [Import Emacs Keyboard Configuration Into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364089/import-emacs-keyboard-configuration-into-eclipse)

It worked for me on upgrading from 3.6 to 3.7 version of Eclipse.

Use: File->export->General and select 'Keys Preferences' 

and 
File -> import -> General

Answer (score 0):

File > Export has the ability to export preferences and you should be able to export in 3.4 and import into 3.6 without issue.

Comment: Sadly, exporting prefs in 3.4 creates a .pref file which 3.6 won't load (it's looking for an .epf extension).

Answer (score 0):

If the traditional way of doing it via the File->Export->Preferences->Keys doesn't work for you, then you can try the following.
Look for the preferences found at:
/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime
That folder contains, among other things, the key bindings.. If you happened to back up your Eclipse 3.4 settings found in org.eclipse.core.runtime you can give it a shot.

You should first experiment with this approach to see if it works for you.

Regards.